# Installing selenium package for multiple anaconda versions

Tags: python, selenium, path, anaconda, conda

I have two python distributions on my computer. I can control where I should install which package so far. However, it is changed for selenium package. I have no idea about the reason and it is somehow installed into another location under VS side. In the current scenario, I expect that the selenium package should be installed on "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages" but this is not the case for selenium.

Any overall understanding about the case and solution ?

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://seleniumhq.org/'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\workspace\PyRecetem\dynamic.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

Current pip version is:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip -V
pip 19.0.3 from C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)
```

Installation command:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>py -3 -m pip install selenium
Requirement already satisfied: selenium in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\lib\site-packages (3.141.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\lib\site-packages (from selenium) (1.25.8)
```

Installed python paths:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>where python
C:\Anaconda3\python.exe
C:\Anaconda2\python.exe
```

Comment: By the way, I know that I can temporarily solve the current issue with this command: C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin>conda install selenium However, I am looking for deeper answer and permanent answer.

Comment: Why do you have anaconda2 and 3? What does `where py` give you in cmd?

Comment: If you're trying to install the package using Anaconda, why even use pip? Have you activated the environment? This should be a non-issue when using Conda.

Comment: @FlyingTeller C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin>where py gives me C:\Windows\py.exe. I am not sure about the difference between py and python in this case ? The reason for anaconda 2 and 3 at the same time, some of my projects are dependent on python2 version and I can not transfer them to python3 for various reasons.

Comment: @AMC The reason using pip is that I am using a couple of packages which are not supported by conda install command. It is not the case for selenium package. However, your answer is not related with the question at all.

Comment: @ozturkib _The reason using pip is that I am using a couple of packages which are not supported by conda install command._ I'm curious, can you share what those packages are? _However, your answer is not related with the question at all._ What answer?

Comment: _The reason for anaconda 2 and 3 at the same time, some of my projects are dependent on python2 version and I can not transfer them to python3 for various reasons._ You can have environments with Python 2 or 3 in Anaconda 3, so I'm not sure I understand what the point is. It's probably just making your development environment even messier.

Answer (score 0):

You said that

> I have two python distributions on my computer.

But it looks like you have three:

```
C:\Anaconda3\python.exe
C:\Anaconda2\python.exe
C:\Windows\py.exe
```

The last probably got installed alongside visual studio, as the `site-packages` are at `c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\lib\site-packages`

So `py -m pip install` did not install to any of your anaconda installations but instead to the version that came with visual studio. Use

```
python -m pip install
```

to install to your anaconda3 distribution.

**Side Note**:

> The reason for anaconda 2 and 3 at the same time, some of my projects are dependent on python2

This is a valid reason to wanting to keep two different python versions around. However, since `anaconda` comes with `conda` built in, the way to go would be to have virtual environments instead of different aanconda installations to avoid the ambiquity of different python installations in the same system. Simply do

```
conda create -n py27 python=2.7
conda create -n py37 python=3.7
```

and then you can `conda activate` whichever python version you might want

Comment: I have only installed two versions of python so far as i explained earlier. However, py.exe is the new Windows launcher, installed automatically. You can see details on https://learning-python.com/py33-windows-launcher.html . The suggestion of python -m pip install is really good one but how can you manipulate the same syntax to install package on python 2.7 on the same computer ?

Comment: If I completely uninstall anaconda2 with the command of C:\Anaconda2>Uninstall-Anaconda2.exe, then do the conda create -n py27 python=2.7, do you think everything will be alright ? Can I give this interpreter path to the eclipse as well without two separate installation ? In this case, I should remove the python installation under the VS side as well ? Could you explain them with reasons/details? Many thanks

Comment: @ozturkib _If I completely uninstall anaconda2 with the command of C:\Anaconda2>Uninstall-Anaconda2.exe, then do the conda create -n py27 python=2.7, do you think everything will be alright ?_ I'm not FlyingTeller but yes, it should work. In fact I just tried it myself, and there were no issues. _Can I give this interpreter path to the eclipse as well without two separate installation ?_ What do you mean? _In this case, I should remove the python installation under the VS side as well ?_ What does that mean? VS = Visual Studio (Code?) ?